# Coding examples for user login for iPhone

Tags: iphone, security, authentication, passwords

I am new in iPhone development. I would learn to create a page where a user needs to login. If the user credentials are correct, then he/she should be allowed to enter the next page in the application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you should give more details if you're expecting an answer.  Your request is too wide.

Comment: just try something and ask your doubts.

Comment: try this, a tutorial for [SimpleLoginScreen](http://www.riccomini.name/Topics/Mobile/iPhone/SimpleLoginScreen/),
And try this repo : [iOSLogin](https://github.com/ijoshsmith/iOSLogin)

Comment: [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3):

here we are calling perform selector sentAuthenticateDetails for web service Authentication.

```
-(IBAction)login_Button_Clicked:(id)sender  
{ 

    [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
    BOOL allFieldsSuccess;

    if((![self.userNameOrEmail_Str length]>0)||(![self.password_Str length]>0)) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"for Login" message:@"Please enter proper Userid & Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];
        NSLog(@"no values");
        allFieldsSuccess = NO;
        return;

    }
    else
    {
      allFieldsSuccess = YES;  
    }

    if (allFieldsSuccess==YES)// && (emailSuccess==YES))
    {

        [self.spinner startAnimating];

        [self performSelector:@selector(sentAuthenticateDetails) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

on your login button give below method...

```
-(IBAction)onClickLogin:(id)sender
{
    if ([txtUserName.text isEqualToString:@""]) 
    {
        ///here paste your Alert View with message:@"Please Fill Up Email and Password"
    }
    else if([txtPassWord.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        ///here paste your Alert View with Message message:@"Please Fill Up Email and Password"        
    }
    ///if here you use web-service for store the user data then give the request with username and password also
    if([txtUserName.text isEqualToString:storeduserName] && [txtPassWord.text isEqualToString:storedpassWord]
    {
       yourViewController *objviewController = [[yourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController objviewController animated:YES];
    }
   else
   {
        ///Alert with username or password is incorrect try again
   }
}
```

also check below Demo...

https://github.com/ijoshsmith/iOSLogin

Hope this help you...
:)

Comment: i think here you are not checking weather given credentials correct or wrong

Comment: no i give the storedUsername where person give the correct username which compare with given username so if both are correct then user can loged in otherwise not allowed to push on next view..

Comment: yes temporary right but see what i write in comment that if you use URL/webservice then get the username and password and replace with storedUsername and storedPassword very easy dude.... :)